# Accessing global variable in css

Tags: css, scope, web-frontend, css-variables

```css
:root { 
  --color: blue; 
}

div { 
  --color: green;
    color: var(--color) 

}

#alert { 
  --color: red; 
    color: var(--color) 
}
```

```html
<p>What's my color?</p>

<div>and me?</div>

<div id='alert'>  
  What's my color too?  
  <p>color?</p>
</div>
```

In the above code, how can I access the global value of --color in div with id='alert'?
Or in other words is there any way in CSS to access the global variable like the :: (scope resolution operator) in c++??

Comment: you mean `var(--color)` ?

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If not you should elaborate on what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can't do that with CSS.

If You'll repeat the declaration of the same variable, it'll use the locally declared variable.

See this-

```css
:root { --color: blue; }
div { --color: green; }
#alert { --color: red; }
* { color: var(--color); }
```

```html
<p>I inherited blue from the root element!</p>
<div>I got green set directly on me!</div>
<div id='alert'>
  While I got red set directly on me!
  <p>I’m red too, because of inheritance!</p>
</div>
```

Source: [Example 5 CSSWG](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables/#defining-variables)

Answer (score 0):

CSS Custom variables are inheritable, that means when you define a variable in `:root`, it is applicable to all elements.

When you applied it to `div` it changed for all div and everything inside the `div`.

And because they have been inherited, their parent's/root's value **can't** be accessed.

Check out this [pen](https://codepen.io/frunkad/pen/zmaaLX) for some trials.

---

One <s>method</s> hack to do is to make a copy of the variable and use it.

```css
:root {
  --color: blue;
  --colorRoot: var(--color);
  color: var(--color);
}

div {
  --color: green;
  color: var(--color);
}

#inside {
  color: var(--colorRoot);
}
```

```html
<div> I am inside a div.<br><span id="inside">I am inside</span></div>

I am ouuuuuutside
```

Pretty sure that's not you would like to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possibility

```css
:root { 
  --color: blue; 
}

div { 
  color: var(--color); 
}

#alert { 
  color: var(--color); 
}
```

```html
<p>What's my color?</p>

<div style="--color:green">and me?</div>

<div id="alert" style="--color:red">  
  What's my color too?  
  <p>color?</p>
</div>
```

Or:

```css
:root { 
  --color: blue; 
}

div { 
  --color: green;
  color: var(--color); 
}

#alert { 
  --color: red;
  color: var(--color); 
}
```

```html
<p>What's my color?</p>

<div>and me?</div>

<div id="alert">  
  What's my color too?  
  <p>color?</p>
</div>
```